# Can't select a row from a pandas dataframe, read from a csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a csv with some data that I'm reading into pandas:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]

data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', header=None)

xy = data

print str(xy)
```

Result:

```
       0                                 1
0  label                              data
1      x                      6,8,10,14,18
2      y                    7,9,13,17.5,18
3      z                         0,0,1,1,1
4      r  2,13,31,33,34,4324,32413,431,666
```

However, when I try to select a frame:

```
xy = data['2']
xy = data['y']
xy = data['label']
```

It just gives me the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Regress[AA]--[01].py", line 10, in <module>
    xy = data['label']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 161, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4084)
KeyError: 'label'
```

How should I be formatting my selection request?

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Merlin's help, I got it working:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')

for i in range(len(df.label)):
    a = str(df['label'][i])
    b = str(df['data'][i])
    print ("Row: {} - Data: {}".format(a,b))
```

Gives me:

```
Row: x - Data: 6,8,10,14,18
Row: y - Data: 7,9,13,17.5,18
Row: z - Data: 0,0,1,1,1
Row: r - Data: 2,13,31,33,34,4324,32413,431,666
```

Comment: Don't change the default header='infer'. Try `pd.read_csv(filename,sep=':')`

Comment: It has to be like that: `x`,`y` and `z` all have 5 values, but `r` has nine. The header has to be `None` or It will give me a error: `ValueError: Some errors were detected ! Line #3 (got 10 columns instead of 6)`

Comment: Wait, that's wrong: it should be line 4.

Comment: ";", the commas are for the arrays: `x = [6,8,10,14,18]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
df       = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
xy       = df
```

Do not name your dataframe "data"; One of your column headers is named `data!`.
 Then: for i, row in df.iterrows():
    a = str(df['label'][i])
    b = str(df['data'][i])
    print ("Row: {} - Data: {}".format(a,b))

```
 print df.head()
 print df.info()
 print df["data"].head()
```

**I dont know what you are expecting**

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = u"""label;data
x;6,8,10,14,18
y;7,9,13,17.5,18
z;0,0,1,1,1
r;2,13,31,33,34,4324,32413,431,666"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text),sep=';')

df

      label                          data
0     x                      6,8,10,14,18
1     y                    7,9,13,17.5,18
2     z                         0,0,1,1,1
3     r  2,13,31,33,34,4324,32413,431,666

df.head()

  label                              data
0     x                      6,8,10,14,18
1     y                    7,9,13,17.5,18
2     z                         0,0,1,1,1
3     r  2,13,31,33,34,4324,32413,431,666

df.info()

   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
label    4 non-null object
data     4 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 136.0+ bytes

df["data"][1]
'7,9,13,17.5,18'

df["label"]
0    x
1    y
2    z
3    r
Name: label, dtype: object
```

Another edit:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    a = str(df['label'][i])
    b = str(df['data'][i])
    print ("Row: {} - Data: {}".format(a,b))
```

Comment: I had to remove `, header=None`  to make it work. How do I get the individual rows, by the label?

Comment: If the answer was correct, mark it as correct, You could upvote also.  Here is tutorial.. https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/UsingPandas.html

Comment: It wasn't. I still can't get the rows, it's giving me a `KeyError`.

Comment: Let me try to read your tutorial though, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: the tutorial still didn't work. For refrence, here's my data: http://pastebin.com/vmrk80d4

Comment: Hey, I got it working. Sorry for being rude, you really helped me, a lot. Your answer is correct.

Comment: No Problem. Good luck.